# React TypeScript: Custom Fetch Hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write a custom fetch hook, but I guess im missing something.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Context } from "../components/context";

const fetchHook = async(url: string, bearer: string, method: string, body: any ) => {
    const { global } = useContext(Context) as {global: any};
    let headers = {'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    if (bearer) headers = {...headers, ...{'Authorization': bearer}}
    if (method === 'GET') return await fetch(global.apiUrl + url, {method, headers});
    else return await fetch(global.apiUrl + url, {method, headers, body});
}

export { fetchHook }
```

The error im getting is `Line 5:  React Hook "useContext" is called in function "fetchHook" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

**UPDATE:**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Context } from "../components/context";


const useFetch = (url: string, bearer: string, method: string, body: any) => {

    const { global } = useContext(Context) as {global: any};
    let headers = {'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    if (bearer) headers = {...headers, ...{'Authorization': bearer}}

    const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
    const apiUrl = global.apiUrl;

    React.useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            let res; 
            if (method === 'GET') res = await fetch(apiUrl + url, {method, headers});
            else res = await fetch(global.apiUrl + url, {method, headers, body});
            setResponse(await res.json());
        } catch (error) {
          setError(error);
        }
      };
      fetchData();
    }, []);

    return { response, error };
  };

  export { useFetch }
```

The only warning I get now I about a missing dependency warning but I'm not sure how to fix it. Should I be passing all the dependencies into the square brackets of useEffect()?? I'm just not sure?

`Line 27:  React Hook React.useEffect has missing dependencies: 'apiUrl', 'body', 'global.apiUrl', 'headers', 'method', and 'url'. Either include them or remove the dependency array`

Comment: Hooks must be used only in react function component (React.FC)

Comment: How are you using fetchHook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this warning because according to the Rules of hooks, a custom hook name must start with `use`.

As mentioned the [docs of custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook)

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use”
>   and that may call other Hooks.

You won't receive the error if you rename the hook to

```
const useFetchHook = async(url: string, bearer: string, method: string, body: any ) => {
    const { global } = useContext(Context) as {global: any};
    let headers = {'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    if (bearer) headers = {...headers, ...{'Authorization': bearer}}
    if (method === 'GET') return await fetch(global.apiUrl + url, {method, headers});
    else return await fetch(global.apiUrl + url, {method, headers, body});
}

export { useFetchHook }
```

Also one thing you must keep in mind is that if you execute async code within the custom hook directly, it will be executed on every render. A better way is to maintain state and fetch the data within `useEffect` and update the state when the data is received.